# php://Input is blank | Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I have spent hours researching and cannot figure out why my messenger bot is not working, I have setup web hooks correctly and FB has approved the setup of the web hook.

```
file_put_contents("fb.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

This code produces no error, but it does not put anything into "fb.txt" file when I send the bot a message.

If I do this, the text in "fb.txt" changes, that shows me that FB is sending requests to the URL, but for some reason "PHP://Input" is not working.

```
file_put_contents("fb.txt", "Its Working");
```

The above code adds "Its working" to the file when I send the bot a message, but it will not add the contents of PHP://INPUT to the file, It just comes up blank?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – hard to tell, with only one-line script snippets ... Have you subscribed your bot to a page as well? Have you tried testing your setup via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#validation

Comment: I did subscribe the bot yes.
It is receiving the calls from Facebook, just PHP://INPUT is actually blank

Thats what I don't understand.

Comment: Can you log the request headers as well? (`apache_request_headers()` or `$_SERVER`, in combination with `var_export`) Also, please use the FILE_APPEND flag with file_put_contents, so that it appends new data to your log file, instead of overwriting it.